# Issue inserting image in header

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm writing a report using multiple R Markdown files, and to facilitate combining them I decided to use the **bookdown** package. I face a problem with inserting a logo as header using **fancyhdr** LaTeX package, that worked fine in a regular `.Rmd` file.

**index.Rmd file:**

```
---
documentclass: book
classoption: openany
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
subparagraph: true
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    toc_depth: 4
    latex_engine: xelatex # to receive Arial as font --> install.packages("xelatex") works for R users
link-citations: yes
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.25
---
```

The **preamble.tex** is:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\pagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{100pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=456px]{INS_logo.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{shurp-2018-logo-blue-transparent.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage \hspace{1pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}

\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=10mm, }

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

Everything works fine except that the necessary logos don't appear in the header. Using the same code in a plain `pdf_document` format works fine.

I guess it has something to do with the book-option - does anyone know more here? I consulted https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/, their github-repo as well as StackOverflow and the documentation on **fancyhdr**.

my sessioninfo (R Studio 1.2.1070):

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 bookdown_0.7    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0     
 [8] Rcpp_0.12.19.3  rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      xfun_0.4        digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.12
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You are specifying the image dimensions in "px" which can only be used by pdfTeX and LauTeX as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/what-are-the-possible-dimensions-sizes-units-latex-understands). I don't think this is the main cause of your problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the images are not being pushed off the top off the page? Without your full directory, I am not able to reproduce your problem but it looks like you haven't specified a large enough `top` value within the geometry argument.  Looking at the documentation to the [geometry](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) LaTeX function, you can see that this specifies the distance between the top of the body and the edge of the paper, leaving no space for your header.

[image]

Here is my reproducible example. It generates a dummy plot `plot.png` which is used for a logo placeholder

**index.Rmd**:

````
---
documentclass: book
classoption: openany
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.25
link-citations: yes
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc_depth: 4
subparagraph: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Create an image to attach
png(filename = "logo.png", width = 200, height = 150, units = "px")
plot(cars)
box('figure', col = 'red')
dev.off()
```

# Title 1

Text

\newpage

## Section

Text

\newpage
````

Within the same directory is the **preamble.tex**. Note the adjusted geometry argument `top=50mm`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\pagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{100pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{logo.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage \hspace{1pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}

\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=50mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

[image]

Comment: I could rebuild your reprex - but as soon as I insert site: bookdown::bookdown_site (for including all chapters) all things defined by **fancyhdr** disappear. What means "without my full directory"? I'm happy to provide more information.

Comment: I just tried adding `site: bookdown::bookdown_site` and the header displays on pages 3 & 4, but not 1 & 2. Is this the same behaviour you are experiencing? Changing to `documentclass: article` makes it show on all the pages.

Comment: yes! but then, when I add a second file.Rmd containing only #titletest (to symbolize a chapter) the **fancyhdr** header/footer-specs disappear. Edit: changing to `documentclass: article` worked in the reprex, but not on the original file.

Comment: Have you adjusted the line `\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=50mm}`? That is the only way I can reproduce your error when I left it as you originally had.

Comment: Yes - I have adjusted everything - see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 
I seem to have had some kind of bug in the system despite reloading everything. I followed the suggestions by Michael Harper but opened the code in a totally new project/folder, then I set the `documentclass: article` inserted a title page manually. What is left now: Getting the headers to work in the tableofcontents and removing the page number (footer, centered).

Index.Rmd:

````
---
documentclass: article
classoption: openany
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.25
link-citations: yes
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
      before_body: before_body.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
subparagraph: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Create an image to attach
png(filename = "logo.png", width = 200, height = 150, units = "px")
plot(cars)
box('figure', col = 'red')
dev.off()
```
````

preamble.tex:

```
% loading necessary LateX-packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% include a fancy header
\pagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{100pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{logo.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage \hspace{1pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}

% set page geometry
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=40mm}

% make the word "Chapter" disappear - only display the chapters name
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

% Following below
% turns maketitle off, then you can define your own titlepage in before_body.tex
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle 
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
```

before_body.tex:

```
% titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\Huge A BOOK}
\linebreak
\includegraphics{cover.png}
\linebreak
{\huge by Me}
\end{center}

\let\maketitle\oldmaketitle
\maketitle
```